# Rational normal curves on quadrics

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quadrics, rational-curves

Given a quadric $Q\subseteq\mathbb{P}^r$ and points $p_1,\dots,p_{r+2}\in Q$ in linear general position, a naive dimension count suggests that one should expect finitely many rational normal curves that pass through the points and lie on $Q$. This is of course not going to be the case in general.

For instance, if $r=3$ and $Q$ is the quadric cone then one can easily show that there exists a twisted cubic on $Q$ passing through $p_1,\dots,p_5$ if and only if $p_1,\dots,p_5$ and the singular point of $Q$ are in linear general position. (If it exists, it will be the unique twisted cubic passing through the singular point and $p_1,\dots,p_5$.)

I want to know if anybody knows a set of conditions on the points $p_1,\dots,p_{r+2}$, which guarantees the existence of at least one rational normal curve on $Q$ through the points.

My primary focus in this problem is the case of rank 3 quadrics, but any ideas for any other ranks (except for rank 1 and 2 of course) will be appreciated.

Comment: If for every partition of your set of points into $S_1$ and $S_2$, the intersection of the span of $S_1$ and the span of $S_2$ (which will be a single point by the assumption of linear general position) does not lie in the quadric, then there will be a rational normal curve in $Q$ through your points. This is because there must be a genus 0 stable map of degree $r$ through your points, and this must necessarily be an embedding of a rational normal curve (all possible degenerate cases can be excluded by our conditions.) Unfortunately there are a lot of details to write out...

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful, but I don't see why there has to be a genus 0 stable map of degree $r$ on $Q$ through my points? How do you show this?

Comment: The space of genus 0 $n$-marked stable maps of degree r to $Q$ is proper, and so the image of the evaluation map $M_{0,n}(Q,r)\rightarrow Q^n$ is going to be a closed subset of $Q^n$. It remains to show that there is a rational normal curve through a generic set of $r+2$ points on $Q$; there should be a lot of ways to do this (I had in mind degenerating $Q$ to a double plane, where this statement can be confirmed by explicit calculation, and then arguing that a rational normal curve in this double plane deforms back to a rational normal curve in Q.)